Excel Formula Incorrect, IF Statement not returning date
Hi new to excel and having difficult time with constructing my formulas.  I have to use an If statement or something similar to get this correct for a school project.
The problem is: create a new column to pull the correct expiration date from the corresponding Store sheet.
create logic for 2 categories:

Movie rental does not have an expiration date: "Contract expires as of N/a"
Movie rental does have an expiration date: "Movie rental expires as of: (insert exp date)

I have a formula that works, but to be clear my spreadsheet is 2 pages and on one page where I am putting my formula in column K I have to use XLookup to cross reference what is in my columns from the 2 pages the xlookup is correct.
The reason i am asking for help is this has me stumped.  I have an equation that works but It needs to be simplified to the most efficient formula for good data practice.  You can use any formula but I really want to figure out an IF statement with the Xlookup or the most efficient If statement.  If that does not work just something else very efficient but If is used a lot in this class and I could use help with it so I can use it in the future once I learn this.
Here is my formula that works but is not efficient.  If someone could help me break it down to an If by
itself or if with xlookup only that would be fantastic or else just something efficient!
=IF(AND(XLOOKUP(A2,'Hollywood Cinema Inputs'!A:A,'Hollywood Cinema Inputs'!K:K)=""),"Contract Expires as of: N/A",IF(XLOOKUP(A2,'Hollywood Cinema Inputs'!A:A,'Hollywood Cinema Inputs'!K:K)<>"",CONCAT("Contract expires as of: ",TEXT(XLOOKUP(A2,'Hollywood Cinema Inputs'!A:A,'Hollywood Cinema Inputs'!K:K),"m/dd/yyyy"))))

Some excel spreadsheets may not require inputs in the formula mine does on this version on my other version it does not so just note that you may have to take the inputs out for it to work.
I tried to use an If statement but it got real complicated real fast trying to simplify it but having trouble constructing an if with x lookup together becuase of the logic

where i have contract it was supposed to be rental my friend was helping me but did not remember to change it back
